# How to set start xml, on Android (Eclipse)

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I am a newbie and I am trying to code a mini android app, and I also recoded some tutorials in the internet - but there is something I still don't understand, in which file I can define which .XML will be the first one shown, when the app starts?

where can I define this?

Comment: It's set in the Activity. There's a method called `setContentView`, and you set the layout file like so `setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, you indicate which Activity class will be the main activity via an `intent-filter`.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.androidtests.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Afterwards, each activity sets its corresponding layout in its `onCreate()` method, via `setContentView()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ....
}
```

Normally, as in this example, you do so by specifying a layout id (corresponding to an XML layout file) but you can also create Views programmatically if need be.

Answer (score 0):

You define your xml in your `res/layout` file and declare it in your class: `setContentView(R.layout.file_name);` in your MainActivity.